# Custom HTML Element doesn't toggle css focus pseudo-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using a tag library for tag input (it's called tagify). This library creates a custom html element called `tags` and it inherits the classes from the original text input used to create the `Tagify` javascript object and then hides it. Inside `tags`, it creates a simple `div` with a `input` inside it.

Before this I was using the bootstrap class `form-control` which has a sort of blue glow/shadow on focus. I want the `tags` to have that on focus effect and it does have that bootstrap class because it's added by Tagify. However, this on focus effect never happens.

In fact when you click it, you're essentially clicking the `input` element, so I installed a event listener on focus that calls the `tags` focus. This didn't work ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ja77t3L4/)). Are custom html elements not "focusable"? Is there a way of adding that effect to the `tags` element?

EDIT:
If I manually check the :focus checkbox in the developer options of the browser it does what I need. Also, I just want the effect, It's not mandatory to use the focus class but I do need it to be the exact same as the one provided by `form-control` even if Bootstrap decides to change it in the future.

EDIT2:
Is there a way to get the css of the focus pseudo class and then add those rules to a new class using javascript? Then on focus in `input` I would add that class to `tags`.

Comment: You can focus on them, but the input is the one getting the focus, not the tag

Comment: The solution would be adding a class to the ``tag`` when input focus

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO How do I make sure the CSS of that new class to be added on focus of the input would be exactly the same as the one provided by bootstrap's `form-control` even if bootstrap decides to change it in the future?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Is there a way to get the css of the focus pseudo class and then add those rules to a new class using javascript? Then on focus I would add that class to `tags`.